# Monoclonal antibody mass production

Tags: medicine, antibody

There is a long conversation taking place these days about monoclonal antibodies against COVID-19. From a few biology courses I had a long time ago, I remember that the process of creating mAbs was a very complex and delicate one, with relatively small yields, something that contributed to the reduced availability and the high price of such treatments.

I wanted to ask because after my research I got even more confused and I couldn't conclude: what is the current, "modern" procedure of mAb production? What are the yields and eventually how logical is to expect a mAb treatment to become widely accessible? Especially though, when "common" mAb therapies like adalimumab and infliximab cost a few thousand euros/year.

Comment: What recent reviews have you consulted? That is the way to find out the current status of technology, rather than expecting someone here to write a pale imitation.

Comment: Welcome to the site. What research have you done on your own to answer this question? The Biology.SE community has agreed that **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Unresearched questions may be subject to down-voting and closure. Please see our [homework policy](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) for more information.

Comment: I am going to edit my question and list the papers I have already read. So please wait before delete/downvote! :) On top of that please keep in mind that I'm not related in any way to Biology other than having an extra interest from childhood. My studies and expertise are lying in a completely unrelated field.